# EJB 3.0 Update then Select is not working properly jboss5.1.0.G

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0

I am getting very strange problem. My problem is that this

FIRST am selecting entity from the database using `EJB 3.0` and `jboss 5.1.0.GA`

```
Subscriber s = (Subscriber)manager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Subscriber s " +
        "WHERE s.subscriber_id = ?1").setParameter(1,123).getSingleResult();
```

Then I am doing update to the entity with query like this

```
int a  = manager.createQuery(" UPDATE Subscriber s SET s.balance = s.balance + "+10+"WHERE s.subscriber_id = ?1").setParameter(1,123).executeUpdate();
```

THEN againg I am selecting the entity like this

```
s = (Subscriber)manager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Subscriber s " +
"WHERE s.subscriber_id = ?1").setParameter(1,123).getSingleResult();
```

BUT I am not getting the updated value of "balance" field BUT as soon as I comment the first `SELECT`  statement I am getting the updated value. But I need the first `SELECT` statement in any case because I want to use it.

Can any one tell me why it is happening and what is its solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would bet this is because of the cache problem.

I will assume that your `manager` is an `EntityManager` instance.

You're executing the first query, so the `PersistenceContext` is fetching the `Subscriber` entity from the database and puts it into the cache. Then, you're executing **batch UPDATE** query which directly hits the database omitting the cache structures, so it doesn't affect the PersistenceContext.
At the end, you execute once again the SELECT query. Doing so, the `PersistenceContext` checks if it have `Subscribe` entity cached somewhere. It does, so it doesn't hit the database but returns the value stored in its cache.

I don't quite get why you're executing **batch UPDATE** query instead of just updating your object state and letting the JPA to commit the changes when appropriate.

So instead of:

```
int a  = manager.createQuery("UPDATE Subscriber s SET s.balance = s.balance +
                             "+10+"WHERE s.subscriber_id = ?1")
                .setParameter(1,123).executeUpdate();
```

you could just do:

```
// 's' is the Subscribe entity previously fetched from the database
s.setBalance(s.getBalance() + 10);
```

Although if you still **really need** to use bach UPDATE then you could try doing

```
manager.refresh(s);
```

after the batch UPDATE query. This will let the JPA access the database instead of its cached version.

If you comment the first SELECT statement, the example works because the `PersistenceContext` didn't cache your entity. It fetches it from the database for the first time just after the batch UPDATE query.

Comment: If it worked and answered your question, feel free to accept this answer.